# How to sort the files by size and based subdirectory un Unix?

Tags: bash, unix

I have the below input data in a file and need to get the output as mentioned below.
Need to sort the data by size(Asc/des)/by subdirectory

```
Below is the input which is there in a file:

120     /root/path2/part-00000-d3700305-428d-4b13-8161-42051f4ac5ed-c000.json
532     /root/path1/part-00000-9aa3e423-084b-406b-8c75-d50c369f1943-c000.json
100     /root/path1/Telephone-bill-September-2019-89051_path.doc
72      /root/path2/BishnuPrasadRout[5_0].doc
4       /root/path2/survey.csv
4       /root/path2/hello.c
4       /root/path1/pages.txt
4       /root/path1/hadoopexam.txt
```

``````````````````````````````````````````
Expected Output

120     /root/path2/part-00000-d3700305-428d-4b13-8161-42051f4ac5ed-c000.json
72      /root/path2/BishnuPrasadRout[5_0].doc
4       /root/path2/survey.csv
4       /root/path2/hello.c
532     /root/path1/part-00000-9aa3e423-084b-406b-8c75-d50c369f1943-c000.json
100     /root/path1/Telephone-bill-September-2019-89051_path.doc
4       /root/path1/pages.txt`*enter code here*`
4       /root/path1/hadoopexam.txt

`````````````````````````````````````````
``````````````````````````````````````````

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: sort -r | sort -k2.12,2.12 -r < file.txt

Comment: cat file.txt | sort -b -r -k1,5 -k12,12

Comment: Got the solution --- sort -t/ -k2,3r -k1,1rn -k4